# How to export to excel datetime in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, excel, datetime, python-3.x

Iam using Django 1.7, Python 3.4 and PostgreSQL 9.1.
I need to export to Excel some queryset. As a starting point I use this guide: [outputting-excel-with-django](http://reliablybroken.com/b/2009/09/outputting-excel-with-django/)

In my model I have a field as a **Datetime**, and in utils.py I added already a style:     `(datetime.datetime, xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS')),`

But when I try to export my data I get a Type Error: `can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is apparently due to [aware and naive datetimes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).

You have to make you datetime objects aware. You can install **pytz** for this:

```
pip install pytz
```

And then make your datetime objects aware :

```
import pytz

(pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime), xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS')),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but after i insert `(pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime), xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS')),` i get a ValueError `Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)`

Comment: Maybe try datetime.datetime.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')) ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. Yes, it worked and helped me a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use xlsxwriter for this
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter